# Windows-10 Download folder slow to display contents

Tags: windows-10

10GB of files: 516 files in 14 folders.

Why does it take a significant amount of time to list contents (10-25 seconds)  in the explorer?  This laptop is maxed out in terms of RAM and has a SSD drive.  No Antivirus is installed.

Comment: This works for many users..Quick fix for very slow to load “Downloads” folder in Windows 7 & 8 | istartedsomething : http://www.istartedsomething.com/20121202/quick-fix-for-very-slow-to-load-downloads-folder-in-windows-7-8/ (also applies to Windows 10)

Answer (score 1):

1. If you add more columns to the explorer display, it becomes horribly slow. check if you have other than the default columns there:Name, Date modified, Type, Size.
2. Disk fragmentation can be a major issue, but only on non-SSD. If so, run `DEFRAG /D C:` in a (admin) command window, or use the graphic interface (disk properties/Tools). On an SSD, forget this, it does not do anything good.
3. ZIPs and other cabinet-style files are slowing it down considerably, as the Explorer looks into them and checks all the content. Not much you can do, except moving them all in a sub-folder.

Comment: Nice answer, you might want to add **4. ** By default Windows 10 has Windows Defender turned on and pro-actively scanning files as they are listed/accessed/used.  If the Downloads folder contains archives and large files, this process can take some time. If the OP has some other antivirus app installed, then *it* might be the cause of the slow-down as most antivirus apps do real-time scanning.

Comment: @misha256 defender is the CAUSE, Defender is very slow

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution is **Reset Folders** and **apply across all your folders** [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/26147306-64c5-466d-a211-5a6a5f012575/why-is-windows-10-file-explorer-is-unaccepably-slow?forum=win10itproapps):

> It might help to reset the windows view to the default settings across
>   all your folders.  If your current view (basically what columns are
>   displayed and how the icons look in each explorer window) requires
>   that each file be opened to access certain information, it will
>   definitely slow it down.
>
> It's an easy fix to apply that default view across all your folders at
>   once.  This means that all your folders will have the view settings of
>   a new installation of Windows 10.
>
> To reset your current file explorer view to default, search for
>   "Folder Options" at the start gem, select "Change search options for
>   files and folders" (it's a control panel widget), and a "Folder
>   Options" dialog will appear. Select the "View" tab, and you'll see
>   "Folder Views" at the top.   Click on the "Reset Folders" button and
>   allow it to apply across all your folders. Then your view will be
>   reset to default across all of your folders.  After applying this, all
>   your folders will appear similarly when you open them.  You may then
>   find that the directories open again with speed.   If you make a
>   change (such as adding a column to show bit rates), and it slows it
>   down, you'll know why.
>
> Why does this work faster?  Because in the default view, windows
>   doesn't need to open each and every file n the directory to pull up
>   the requested info to show in the view, so it's much faster.

credits for: **BigJohnnyO**

Comment: Had the same issue as OP.  This worked brilliantly.